# Graph mail API returns 504 gateway timeout error

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

```
**(Caused by ResponseError('too many 504 error responses'))

/v1.0/users/xyz@zxx.com/mailFolders/Inbox/messages?%24top=999&%24filter=from%2FemailAddress%2Faddress+ne+%27submissions%40amcapins.com%27+and+receivedDateTime+ge+2021-02-01T05%3A00%3A00%2B00%3A00+and+receivedDateTime+le+2021-02-08T04%3A59%3A59%2B00%3A00 'too many

504 error responses**
```

When we fetch the messages of more than 3 days we gets this error, but its is occasionally not every time, why we got such issue from the graph API. any one please tell me if we need to take care something or we need to change as request to the API .

Answer (score 0):

Try to use smaller page. From your request I see that your page size is 999 which is a large page size. The 504 error is probably caused by the page size.

Graph API calls Outlook API undercover and has to wait for a response with 999 emails, applies filter etc. and then send them in the response to you.

Optimal page size should be 100-300.

Comment: Thank you for your response but even after top = 100  the same error is coming .. but as mentioned this error coming occasionally not everytime...

Comment: Always try using the smaller sizes, not the upper limit. Go for smaller sizes to avoid the throttling. HTTP 504 also tells there might be something wrong from the backend server as well, which might due to the complex filtering that you're using as well.